# WPF setting an ItemSource property of a DataGrid inside a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a ControlTemplate with a DataGrid:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="milling">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="grdMilling">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Modo" Width="44" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=Mode, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>                   
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>                   
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the ContentControl in which I render the grid (this is an example but I have:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ccMilling_1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ContentTemplate="{ StaticResource milling}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="ccMilling_2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ContentTemplate="{ StaticResource milling}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

In code-behind I have a collections of custom item in order to fill the DataGrid and I set the Content

```
ccMilling_1.Content= myCollection1;
ccMilling_2.Content= myCollection2;
```

I'm pretty sure that my collections have all properties set but with this code I cannot render the DataGrid as I dunno how to set the ItemSource property of my dataGrid. How to proceed?

Comment: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">` should work. Having a DataGrid in a ControlTemplate looks odd however. Consider using a DataTemplate instead. You already have that as a tag on your question. With a DataTemplate, you would write `ccMilling_1.Content = myCollection1;`.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the code and I used the DataTemplate. If I set the ItemSource as you written, basically both datagrid have the same collection

Comment: I can't see your changed code. You should however use such a DataTemplate as the ContentTemplate of your ContentControls. That would happen automatically if you declare the DataTemplate resource with an appropriate DataType.

Comment: @Clemens I've updated the code

Comment: That should of course work. No idea what else might be wrong.